# setTimeOut Arrgument Passing

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript I want to use the `setTimeOut()` function like this

```
<script>    
var id=12;

setTimeOut("showGrid('i want to pass variable id here')",5000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this would be to pass an anonymous **function** to setTimeout.  This anonymous function will be able to access `id`

```
setTimeout(function() { showGrid(id); }, 5000);
```

Passing a string to `setTimeout` (instead of a function) is usually considered evil, since the string will be `eval`'d, and should be avoided.

Also note that you had a slight typo in your code: the function is `setTimeout`, not `setTimeOut` (note the lowercase `o`)

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, the code would look like this:

```
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById().inerHTML = data; }, 500);
```

except of course you need to pass some sort of id to `document.getElementById`

Comment: Why the extra complexity when you can use the optional params in `setTimeout`?

Comment: @DemianBrecht - you're right - the extra complexity is only needed if id isn't globally available -- I should have written that first.

Comment: setTimeout(document.getElementById().inerHTML=data, 500);
shall i give like this is it correct?

Comment: @Demian Brecht: Because of cross-browser compatibility issues. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use parameters, try this example:

```js
var x = "OK";
setTimeout(alertOK.bind(null,x), 3000);
x = "Would be WRONG";
console.log("before timeout:", x);

function alertOK(x){
 console.log("after timeout:",x);
}
```

It also works when in loop (where creating functions is not advisable).