# setTimeOut execute function with parameter

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686547/settimeout-arrgument-passing), and I'm wondering what is the problem with this?

```
var id = 12;
setTimeout( showGrid ( 'i want to pass variable ' + id + ' here' ), 5000 );
```

I read the question I'm interested in what the code above is not a good solution. I've only Chrome installed, I've tried it and it works. Is there any browser issue with it?

Why the anonymous function is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a closure:

```
var id = 12;
setTimeout(function() {
    showGrid('i want to pass variable ' + id + ' here');
}, 5000);
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eHWHH/).

edit(Milo) from the comments:

> the setTimeout function expects a callback or a string variable. You are not passing such thing so your code is invalid. You are directly invoking the showGrid function which is not how it is supposed to work. The showGrid function should be invoked only 5 seconds later.

Comment: Ok, but WHY is this better? What could be the problem with the other code snippet?

Comment: @Milo, which other code snippet? The one shown in your question? If yes, the snippet shown in your question doesn't work.

Comment: `setTimeout( showGrid ( 'i want to pass variable ' + id + ' here' ), 5000 );` - this one.

Comment: @Milo, the setTimeout function expects a callback or a string variable. You are not passing such thing so your code is invalid. You are directly invoking the `showGrid` function which is not how it is supposed to work. The showGrid function should be invoked only 5 seconds later.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimout` expects a function as its first argument and a time as its second argument, then optional arguments to pass to the function. So, if you have a function:

```
function showGrid( str ) {
    return str;
}
```

and you have the following `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout( showGrid( "..." ), 5000 );
```

then you are calling `showGrid` and passing the return value to `setTimeout`, so it ends up like this:

```
// "..." is returned from showGrid( "..." )
setTimeout( "...", 5000 );
```

and `"..."` is not a function. So there are two ways to get around this, you can make an enclosure (as in Darin's answer), or add the argument after the time.

```
setTimeout( function() {
    showGrid( "..." );
}, 5000 );

// same thing
setTimeout( showGrid, 5000, "..." );
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fFg57/

Comment: Becareful. It doesn't work on all IE versions, that's why it's better to use a function that returns another function. That's even better than passing a string, because eval can be unsecure.

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = 12;
setTimeout( "showGrid ( 'i want to pass variable " + id + " here' )", 5000 );
```

the first parameter takes a string, much like what you would pass to a `eval` function.

and notice the Small `o` in `setTimeout`