# How to make a variable timer sequence which runs infinitive

Tags: javascript

I have `n` parameters which have to be run in sequence for `t` seconds each. All the data is stored in an array which is loaded dynamically through ajax and json and exists of: function parameters `p` and time to sleep `t`

`function(p1)`, for 30 seconds; when it completes `function(p2)` for 15 seconds etc etc

Until the array is complete; then we  have to start all over.
The number of parameters and its time being displayed are not determined on forehand.

How can I implement this with javascript?

//edit:
I tried to make one big function with function(p1) starting at t=0; function(p2) starting at t=t1; function(p3) starting at t=t1+t3

But it felt 'stupid' and overdone....

Comment: does `function(p1)` takes 30 seconds to return, or you want to wait 30 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you array looks like

```
var myarray=[['p1',30],['p2',15] ...];
```

In this case you could

```
function runme(i) {
  if (i>=myarray.length) i=0;
  var p=myarray[i][0];
  var t=myarray[i][1];
  myfunction(p);
  i=i+1;
  window.setTimeout('runme('+i+');',1000*t);
}
```

**Edit**

And ofcourse

```
runme(0);
```

to start.

Comment: Use an anonymous function instead of a string as the argument to `setTimeout()` - that would make it much more simple+reliable to pass the array and the position. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686547/settimeout-arrgument-passing

Comment: @AaronDigulla 1.) My code was meant to be instructive, not productive: See also me pulling out p and t which is completly unnecessary. 2.) I have had bad experiences passing anonymous functions into IE6. So I keep using the string version, as long as this denomination of a browser is araound. The main argument (security) is not applicable here, as the string is constructed without any user input.

Comment: The first thing I did to adjust the script to my needs was getting rid of the p and t variable :)